# Sub-Items Not Visible in Navigation

Tags: menus, navigation

I backed up and ran an update for WordPress and my websites' plugins. Now the sub items in the navigation bar are not visible. They are published/public. I can access them in the backend as pages.

I do not know if this is a result of the update/something to do with the code. Should I restore the WordPress back to the backup? Or is this something to do with changed code? (Not sure if the website was set up with custom code or not...)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you didn't change the theme to something else, then change it back to the original theme?

In any case, look at Appearance, Menu to see if your menu is set up as you wish it to be. Then check to ensure that the menu is selected to be used by your theme.